# If logic not working as expected

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a char variable in if statement logic and it is not working as I would expect.

```
int main()
{
char a = 'a';
//char array[] = "testing";
if(a=='i'||'b')
{
    cout << "GOOD" << endl << a << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid Char" << endl << a << endl;
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

I would expect this to output

```
Invalid Char
a
```

But it outputs

```
GOOD
a
```

Help?

Comment: You need to use `if (a == 'i' || a == 'b')`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing in your `if` statement correctly. The compiler sees the following

```
if(a=='i'||'b')
```

And sees:

1. Is `a` equal to `'i'` OR
2. Is `'b'` true?

And the second part is always true (because `'b'` must be distinct from the NUL character `'\0'`). What you need to do instead is

```
if (a == 'i' || a == 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem:

```
if(a=='i' || a=='b')
```